# the website doesn't work on IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net

my website gives an error when i want to access Search.aspx page. it works on visual stdio 2010 and there is no error ,but when i added  it to iis server it doesn't.
please anyone can help i'm stack.

here is the error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'Searcharoo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

> Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true"%>
>
> Line 2:  <%@ Import Namespace="Searcharoo.Common" %>

Comment: please add refence Searcharoo.Common dll in a bin folder in IIS

Comment: i added it , i don't know why it can see Searcharoo.Common i gave it a full control and security permission but nothing change :(

Comment: What version of .net is Searcharoo.Common, and what version is your web project? I have had issues before when my library is .net 4 Client Profile, and my Web project is .net 4 (for example)

Comment: my library is 3.5  and web project is 4

Comment: please check your IIS framework